# How can I write down all replications result of Arena sim via Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, arena-simulation

My aim is to run Arena simulation via Excel VBA and get results of simulation to Excel. I wrote some codes.

As you can see, my codes start Arena simulation. And parameter "j" holds the solution of simulation. What I want is that write down all replications result. For example, j1 (result of first replication), j2, j3 ... etc. How can I do that?

```
Sub Test()

Dim oArenaApp As Arena.Application
Dim oModel As Arena.Model, oSIMAN As Arena.SIMAN
Dim oModule As Arena.Module

Set oArenaApp = CreateObject("Arena.application")
ModName = "D:\Model2.doe"
Set oModel = oArenaApp.Models.Open(ModName)
Set oSIMAN = oModel.SIMAN
oArenaApp.Activate
oArenaApp.Visible = True

oModel.BatchMode = True
oModel.QuietMode = True
oModel.Go (smGoWait)

i = oSIMAN.SymbolNumber("Entity 1")
j = oSIMAN.EntitiesNumberOutOfType(i)

oModel.End
oArenaApp.Visible = False

End Sub
```

Comment: I assume you're running this code from Excel? If so, you could e.g. do the following:

Worksheets("results").Range("A2").Value = i   And

Worksheets("results").Range("B2").Value = j

Do you have to run your model multiple times to get the j2, j3 etc?

Comment: Yes I am running this code from Excel. I dont want to run model multiple times. I need proper library object to get every replication result. Arena simulation has library in VBA. But I cannot get every replication output.

Answer (score 0):

If you include VBA in your Arena model, it can read and write an Excel workbook. Arena has "Smart Files Library" which are essentially tutorials.

You may find some value from "`VBA Reading Writing Excel Using VBA Module.doe`: Reading and writing to Excel using the VBA module"